# How to convert framebuffer to image?

Tags: android, screenshot

In my application I want to get the screenshot of my rooted device. I am using the following code to achieve this:

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);    
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();   
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));                                           
os.flush();
```

But I am not getting any image stored.

Comment: do you have a rooted phone?

Comment: @Daniel: The question suggests it is.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor  write now I am trying with emulator(rooted).

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15208592/312312)

Comment: @Lefteris but its not working

Comment: please help some one I am not getting any  source to complete it.